# Is there a "Workflow Engine" implementation for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, workflow, workflow-engine

For (application) server development with Delphi, I would like to use a workflow engine similar to the existing implementations for other programming languages (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine). Is there already an implementation or should I better write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another one:

Workflow studio from Tms Software

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/workflow.asp

Answer (score 2):

There's a commercial product [Common Knowledge](http://www.objectconnections.com/workflow.html) which incorporates workflow and business rules.

Comment: It looks like it is can be used only via ActiveX from Delphi, not compiled into the executable. But at least it offers a Delphi API, so it is worth a try.